# How to write the parsed contents of PDF file to text file?

Tags: powershell, pdf

I wanted to copy the content of PDFs file into a text file using PowerShell. I was able to parse the contents of PDFs using the below code, but I don't know how to copy the parsed data into text file.

```psh
Add-Type -Path .\itextsharp.dll
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList "$pwd\test.pdf".

for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++) {
  $lines = [char[]]$reader.GetPageContent($page) -join "" -split "`n"
  foreach ($line in $lines) {
    if ($line -match "^\[") {   
      $line = $line -replace "\\([\S])", $matches[1]
      $line -replace "^\[\(|\)\]TJ$", "" -split "\)\-?\d+\.?\d*\(" -join ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @NithinAV Please use the `edit` link under the question to update it, instead of posting code as a comment

Comment: As an aside: There are many reasons why you should not extract text from PDFs like that: **1** text encoding might differ from any standard encoding you assume resulting in gibberish; encoding in PDFs is defined font-wise **2** You only look at the immediate page content but sometimes the page content merely references some form xobjects which in turn contain the text **etc**. Try using the iTextSharp parser namespace classes instead.

Comment: I don't know how to use iTextSharp parser namespace class. Can you please help me out on where to get this namespace class and how to include this class to my code?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to assign the output of your `for` loop to a variable, and then write that to a file:

```psh
$data = for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++) {
          ...
        }

$data | Out-File 'C:\path\to\your.txt' -Encoding UTF8
```